# While-loops keep repeating, Debug error when program stops

Tags: c, runtime-error, stack-corruption

I am using Visual Studio 2010.
while is keep repeating and I get an error when program stops.

It is just increasing the value of the array 700 times more than it should, and the "line" shows that it's just repeating the while loop more than it should (~700 times more)

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

     int loop,loop2,loop3,usergirdi,random,linecounter,s,b,x;
     int a[17];
     printf("baslayarak \n");
     scanf("%d",&usergirdi);

     for (loop=1;loop<=16;loop++){
         a[loop]=0; }
     for (loop2=1;loop2<=15;loop2++){
            if(loop2==usergirdi){
                usergirdi=usergirdi;
                a[usergirdi]+=1;
                printf("%d ",a[usergirdi]); }

            else
                printf("%d ",a[loop2]);}

    linecounter=0;

    printf("\n");

while (a[1]<1||a[15]<1||a[2]<1||a[3]<1||a[4]<1||a[5]<1||a[6]<1||a[7]<1||a[8]<1||a[9]<1||a[10]<1||a[11]<1||a[12]<1||a[13]<1||a[14]<1){

linecounter++;

         srand ( time(NULL) );
            random=(rand()%15+1);



     if (a[random-1]==0 && a[random+1]==0 && a[random]==0 ){}

     else if (a[random-1]!=0 || a[random+1]!=0 )
                {
                    a[random]+=1;

     }
    for (b=0;b<=14;b++){
        printf("%d ",a[b]); }
     printf("[line %d]\n",linecounter);



}}
```

---

Debug error:

[image]

Comment: Please reduce your code to the **minimum** compilable code needed to reproduce this error. Probably you'll also find that you solved your problem.

Comment: Are alarm bells not ringing with that hideous `while` condition?

Comment: Alarm bells: `a[-1]=0;`. The error message even tells you that.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour detected! (`a[16]` is not a valid location and so is `a[-1]`)

Comment: If I delete a[-1] it would be something like "-854....." so i keep that part and if I delete it program isn't running correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is subject to undefined behavior. You are accessing the array using an out of bound index in several places.

1. Before the start of the `while` loop.

   ```
   a[16] = 0;
   ```
2. Inside the `while` loop.

   ```
   a[16] = 0;
   a[-1] = 0;
   ```
3. Again inside the `while` loop

   ```
   if (a[random-1]==0 && a[random+1]==0 && a[random]==0 ){}
      // ^^ If random == 0
   ```
4. Again inside the `while` loop

   ```
   else if (a[random-1]!=0 || a[random+1]!=0 )
           // ^^ If random == 0
   ```

You can remove those errors by:

1. Using

   ```
   a[15] = 0;
   ```
2. Replacing the line

   ```
   a[-1] = 0;
   ```

   with

   ```
   a[0] = 0;
   ```
3. Changing the line that generates `random` to:

   ```
   random=(rand()%14)+1;
   ```

The errors in logic can be removed by:

1. Moving the call to `srand` outside the while loop.
2. Removing the `a[0] < 1` check from the `while` loop's conditional.

Comment: so if I extend the array range then would it solve the repeating problem ?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that so I did extended the array.But it still is repeating way more than it should

Answer (score 0):

```
a[16]=0;
```

This array index runs from `0-15` `a[16]` is array out of bound access and leads to UB.

Get rid of this also :

```
a[-1]=0;
```

Comment: UB? what is it mean ?

Comment: @Zavolar Undefined behavior(UB)

Comment: Ok. I just deleted all "a[16]" parts and still I get corruption error

Comment: Ok now there's no corruption I extended the array but it still is repeating 700x times more